# How to avoid next functions in the pipeline while using futures

Tags: scala, future

What is the optimum way to stop/skip the following function based on the current result from a future value?

Assume I have 3 function which returns `Future[Boolean]` like this:

```
def funA() : Future[Boolean] = Future(true) 
def funB() : Future[Boolean] = Future(false) 
def funC() : Future[Boolean] = Future(true)
```

I need to avoid calling `funC` as I get `false` from `funB`.

### Edit

1. When the current function fails, recover with a previously successful one.

   - In the current scenario when `funB` fail return result of `funA` i.e `true`.
2. Need to execute all the function as long as there is no failure.

   - In the current scenario if `funB` returned `true` then `funC` return value is the outcome of all the calls.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a for comprehension with an if statement.  Its not clear what you want the result to be when `funB` is false so you can replace the `Future.failed` with a success if you want a default successful value:

```
for {
  result1 <- funA()
  result2 <- funB()
  result3 <- if(result2) funC() else Future.failed(new Exception("funB was false"))
} yield {
  "Completed!"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A less compact, but (hopefully!) more didactic example:

```
it("Future chain evaluation") {
  var aWasCalled = false
  var bWasCalled = false
  var cWasCalled = false

  def futureA = Future {
    aWasCalled = true
    true
  }

  def futureB = Future {
    bWasCalled = true
    false
  }

  def futureC = Future {
    cWasCalled = true
    true
  }

  val futureEvaluationResult = futureA.flatMap { a =>
    if (!a) Future.successful(false)
    else {
      futureB.flatMap { b =>
        if (!b) Future.successful(false)
        else futureC
      }
    }
  }

  futureEvaluationResult.map { evaluationResult =>
    evaluationResult shouldBe false
  }

  aWasCalled shouldBe true
  bWasCalled shouldBe true
  cWasCalled shouldBe false
}
```